# Executing client side vbscript block with jquery

Tags: jquery, vbscript

Im trying to change the bahavior in some ads written in javascript and load them after page load is completed.

These ads are filled with document.write:s(doesnt work after page is loaded) so i had to overwrite this function and append the code with jquery instead.

Thing is the script contains this part

```
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt language="VBScript"> \n');
document.write('on error resume next \n');
document.write('ShockMode = (Isobject(Createobject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.9")))\n');
document.write('<\/scr' + 'ipt>\n');
```

that gives me this code from my overwritten document.write

```
<script language="VBScript">
on error resume next
ShockMode = (Isobject(Createobject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.9")))
<\/script>
```

But when i append this script with jquery its seems to be ignored.

Is there any way to append vbscript after page is done loading?

Answer (score 0):

if i remember correctly its easy to call a vbscript function from javascript.  Why not create a seperate file that holds the vbscript, link to it from your html page and then simply call the vbscript function at the bottom of your page e.g Somevbmethod

You'll need to put the link to the vbscript file after your links to your js files.  e.g

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/SimpleAutoEllipse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/vbscript" language="vbscript"></script>
```